How to convert a JSON into a OpenAPI using online tools
I'd like to know how I can convert a JSON into a openAPI, I'm aware that there are a few services available for generating JSON Schemas, such as DevToolsDaily and Liquid Technologies.
However, my goal is to create an OpenAPI specification using online tools and achieve a result similar to the example below:
Example os JSON
{
    "root": {
        "processes": {
            "process": [
                "Planned Orders",
                "List Componets",
                "sadsa",
                "asdas",
                "sadas",
                "sdad",
                "dass"
            ]
        },
        "actions": {
            "action": [
                "CREATE",
                "CHANGE"
            ]
        }
    }
}

Looking forward to your guidance!
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Example API
  version: 1.0.0
  description: OpenAPI specification converted from the provided JSON schema.
paths:
  /example:
    post:
      summary: Example endpoint
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Root'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
                    example: "Operation successful"
components:
  schemas:
    Root:
      type: object
      required:
        - root
      properties:
        root:
          type: object
          required:
            - processes
            - actions
          properties:
            processes:
              type: object
              required:
                - process
              properties:
                process:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                  minItems: 7
                  maxItems: 7
            actions:
              type: object
              required:
                - action
              properties:
                action:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                  minItems: 2
                  maxItems: 2

